# Is AMQP transport 3.6.2 compatible with Mule 3.7.*?

Tags: mule, amqp, transport

I've got some strange unexplained problems with a couple of apps after upgrading to Mule 3.7.0. I haven't conclusively proven that they fail because of anything to do with AMQP - the error messages are really nondescript and don't point the finger at any particular component, but AMQP is the only additional component I'm using, and although I see that it's been upgraded to 3.7.0-SNAPSHOT, that version doesn't seem to have been published anywhere yet.

Does anyone have experience running like this, either good, or bad?

Comment: Is it, or ApiKit likely to run into this? https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/wiki/%5BMule-3.7.0-M1%5D-Registry-Consolidation,-Lifecycle-fix,-and-Dependency-Injection

Comment: I actually fixed my issue which turned out to be an old version of ApiKit (1.6.1) which needed upgrading manually to 1.7.1 by editing pom.xml for each project concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, it's completely compatible.

As mentioned in my comment above, my problem was actually ApiKit which needed manually upgrading. Now my apps deploy and run correctly again on Mule 3.7.1